# How to pass Vim function argument to a command?

Tags: vim

I'm using the following function + command to invoke the debugger in Vim:

```
function! TermDebugArm(executable)
    packadd termdebug
    let g:termdebugger="arm-none-eabi-gdb"
    Termdebug a:executable
endfunction

command! -complete=file -nargs=1 TermDebugArm :call TermDebugArm(<f-args>)
```

Unfortunately, the `Termdebug` command gets the literal argument "a:executable" and not the actual value it should represent (i.e. the filename passed to the command that called the function).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `:execute` command to build a command from strings, which will allow you to use the value of `a:executable` as a literal:

```
execute "Termdebug ".a:executable
```

Or you can use the feature of `:execute` that will join multiple arguments with a space, so you don't need an explicit concatenation:

```
execute "Termdebug" a:executable
```

See `:help :execute`.